# Which material is most efficient for the skin of a solar balloon?

Tags: materials, aerospace-engineering, thermodynamics

Quoting from the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_balloon):

> A solar balloon is a balloon that gains buoyancy when the air inside is heated by the sun's radiation, usually with the help of black or dark balloon material.  The heated air inside the solar balloon expands and has lower density than the surrounding air. As such, a solar balloon is similar to a hot air balloon.

What material would be the most efficient (minimize material mass, maximize payload, maximize heat retention) for weaving the skin of a solar hot air balloon? I want to consider thermal conductivity of the outer surface, radiance of the inner one, and structural strength. I want to achieve the 60 metric tons payload lifted to at least 200 meters over tropical sea level.

Comment: What details can you give us about the design of your balloon? Please read [this community wiki about design questions](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/a/190/368). We would be glad to help you with your design but you have to give us more than a concept.

Comment: @Air  I think it is a pretty good question now with the added definition of a solar balloon.

Comment: The lack of definition for a solar balloon is not the problem with this question. Juan asks which material is most efficient, but doesn't give enough specification as to how he determines that. When you say "most efficient" and then give 3 measuring factors, you have to state how you want those weighted. Specify minimums on the outer absorptivity, inner reflectivity, or payload weight. I could select materials that keep nearly all the heat in, but take 2 days to absorb enough heat to inflate. I could argue that's efficient, but not in the way you want.

Comment: @TrevorArchibald I think given the application, reasonable assumptions can be made about what he means by most efficient.  You're example is, as you've alluded to, clearly not what he is looking for.

Comment: Yes! indeed sorry i've been away for a while... by most efficient i mean maximum payload, maximum elevation and maximum tensile strength, minimum material mass (note: i would like it tied down at all times so must account for rope weight, and tensile strength etc...) to limit the question lets say a mark of 60 metric tons net payload is desired.

Comment: I don't care if it takes 5 days to heat if it can keep most of that heat from escaping.

Comment: in fact @TrevorArchibald maintaining heat inside the solar balloon throughout the night would be most welcome.

Comment: the sixty metric tons must be lifted to a minimum of 200 meters above sea level

Comment: @Trevor Archibald I actually don't mind if it takes long to inflate. Maintaining heat inside would be most favorable for my purposes, especially if enough can be maintained to sustain buoyancy over night.

Answer (score 2):

It is a very broad question as there are many design considerations involved, but a good place to start is looking at BoPET(mylar) because it has a high strength to weight ratio and can be made very thin.

Clear mylar on the outside, possibly reflective mylar on the north, and black mylar on the inside. There are lots of other ways to optimize once you have clearer picture of the design.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BoPET